# java: Field change notification using AOP

Tags: java, spring, aop

We have a class with "special" fields. The field type is String, but it can take only a set of defined values. The values it can take on are specified by "type" and each type has a set of defined values.

For instance,

```
class MyClass {
    // Special Field of "TypeA"
    String zimbra;
}
```

`zimbra` can be assigned only a set of values - "ValueA1, ValueA2, etc."

If `zimbra` is of "TypeB", it can be assigned - "ValueB1, ValueB2, etc." The types and values are configured in a persistent store.

We would like to validate the field value assignments. This can be done using [Observer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955588/java-object-changed-fields-listener-design-pattern) or [property field change listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html). But we would like to simplify it using AOP (Spring annotations or AspectJ).

Please suggest if AOP can be used as a solution here.

Comment: I wonder why you do not encapsulate your special types into classes ensuring correct validation. Anyway, as Serge said, AspectJ can be used to do what you want even if it was not invented for patching up bad design. In order to answer your question though, I need to know how you determine the "type" of any plain String field. Please provide a few examples of what your database looks like so as to enable me to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Spring AOP has some limitations :

- it can only be applied on beans created by the application context where you declared the aspect. In particuliar it is of no use on objects created by `new`.
- it is mainly used on object implementing inferfaces (and can only intercept interfaces methods)
- if directly proxying classes (via javassist), objects must have a default constructor

AspectJ will be able to do it because it is far more powerful than Spring AOP, but you will have to deal with its weaving.

Comment: Thanks @Serge. Please outline how we AspectJ can be used here.

Comment: @gammay : sorry I cannot. I mainly use Spring AOP, and only know what I've read around. Anyway, I think I is a little too broad. Try to google arount to find tutorials and documentation. I can only give some links : [AspectJ Tutorial](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~in0980/bib/JanofskyAspectJTutorial.html) and [The AspectJTM Programming Guide](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/index.html)