# What is the most generic solution to look after changes of the fields of an entity in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, aop

I was looking around to find what it is the best solution regarding observing changes of the fields of an entity. I want something generic and maybe to be used in other application in the future ( i was thinking of building a lib).
Some of the solution i found were:

- AOP:

```java
@Aspect
public class AuditAnnotationAspect {

        @Autowired
        private EntityManager entityManager;
    
        @Before("execution(* com.publicis.sapient.engagement.app.repository.RoleRepository.save(..)) && args(newRole)")
        public void before(Role newRole) {
            Role currentRole = entityManager.find(Role.class, newRole.getId());
        }

}
```

- Field Listener:
  [Java object, changed fields listener, design-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955588/java-object-changed-fields-listener-design-pattern)
- Hibernate Envers
- Hibernate Interceptors

But none of them seem to give me the genericity i am looking for, maybe there are still ideas that i have not found.

Comment: u haven't said what exactly is lacking in the AOP approach? What criteria would allow for "genericity" that you are looking for? Every single possible mutation point in the whole application is a tall order, perhaps start with satisfying a specific use case and add as your requirements grow?

Comment: If you are looking for JPA to update only modified field of an entity, try @DynamicUpdate(true). This will generate update query for only modified fields